# DSX desktop installation is stuck at "dockerPull entered" phase

Tags: dsx-desktop

Installing DSX Version: 1.2.2 on a Windows 7 VM, it is stuck at "dockerPull entered" phase shown in dsx-desktop.log:

```
.......
[2018-03-27 16:01:12:0535] [info] Regenerating the certificates
[2018-03-27 16:01:13:0258] [info] Internet Connection reconnected, setting isInternetBad to false
[2018-03-27 16:01:13:0364] [info] Internet Confirmed true ++ true
[2018-03-27 16:01:16:0831] [debug] #OS: Windows
[2018-03-27 16:01:16:0831] [info] Confirming Docker Host for Windows
[2018-03-27 16:01:17:0365] [debug] #GENERATE WINHOST
[2018-03-27 16:01:18:0149] [info] Passed storage check, prefix: B
[2018-03-27 16:01:18:0149] [info] dockerPull entered.
```

Answer (score 0):

We already release DSX V1.2.3. Please download the latest version from [dsx-desktop](http://datascience.ibm.com/desktop). You should be able to fix your issue afterward. let us know if you still have the same problem with V1.2.3.